# Not able to move files between SFTP locations using SFTP Sample in JMeter

Tags: ssh, jmeter, sftp

I am using SSH SFTP Sampler for SFTP testing in jmeter. I am able to GET/REMOVE/IS files/folders from SFTP locations, PUT files from local locations to SFTP. But the issue is that I'm not able to Move files between SFTP locations! Can someone advise on this please!

I tried this but this is only for FTP and not SFTP:

`    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect("SFTP server");
client.login("username", "password");   

client.rename("location2/file.text", "location1/file.txt");
client.logout();
client.disconnect();`
```

Comment: The code in your question appears to be for FTP. If you're having trouble with SFTP, and you have code for SFTP, you should include that in your question. You should also show exactly how it's failing. Are you getting an error message? What exactly does the error say?

Comment: I just picked up this piece of code from someone's answer for FTP and trying to get the same answer for SFTP! In my case, the SSH Sampler has "Source Path" and "Destination Path"; if you put SFTP server in the "Source Path" it will try to pick it up from you local machine and will show you "File is not exist" error message.

Comment: This is the error:D:\jmeter3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\apache-jmeter-3.1\bin\TEST\TEST\CloudFile1.txt (The system cannot find the path specified) where TEST\TEST\CloudFile1.txt is the Source path in the SSH Sampler!

Answer (score 0):

FTP and SFTP are totally different beasts and they use different protocols under the hood.

Given there is no "move" or "rename" action support in the [SSH SFTP](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-sftp) you can still do the same using [SSH Command sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command). The relevant configuration would be something like:

[image: JMeter SSH Command Example]

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

You can install `SSH Command` sampler as a part of `SSH Protocol Support` bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image: Blazemeter SSH Plugins JMeter Plugins Manager]